# Automator error (System Events got an error: Can’t get checkbox)

Tags: applescript, automator, macos-mojave

I have an automator app that switch the audio between mono and stereo. It used to work but Mojave update seems to break it. I have given it accessibility permission, but still no luck. What might be the problem?

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    launch
    reveal anchor "Hearing" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.5
        click the checkbox "Play stereo audio as mono" of window "Accessibility"
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

The error message is as following:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got
>   an error: Can’t get checkbox "Play stereo audio as mono" of window
>   "Accessibility" of process "System Preferences".”

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this a shot...

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Hearing" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists of checkbox "Play stereo audio as mono" of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Play stereo audio as mono" of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! I wonder what does the "group 1" mean? Is it what makes my code not working?

Comment: @johan456789, adding `of group 1 ...` makes it work because Apple changed the object layout of that window in macOS Mojave compared to previous versions of macOS.  Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: A wee tip I hope is beneficial: try to avoid using `delay` commands for anything that script functionality relies upon.  When scripting the UI, it's better (more reliable/robust) to test for existence of an element as a condition for the script to proceed.  This can be done with a short `repeat` loop, in which a `delay` command is used in a non-essential manner: as a loose example, `repeat until the checkbox named "Foo bar" exists`...`delay 0.5`...`end repeat`.